# My function doesn't return a value, can't figure out why

Tags: python, function, return

The function is supposed to open a csv file that has data in this format

"polling company,date range,how many polled,margin of error,cruz,kasich,rubio,trump"

When I run this function, read_data_file, there is no output, which I don't understand since I am returning the poll_data. I don't believe there is an issue with the rest of the code as if I replaced 'return poll data' with 'print(poll_data)' there is the desired output.

I am a noob at this and don't have a full grasp of return.

```
def read_data_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    poll_data = []
    for data in file:
        data = data.strip('\n')
        data = data.split(',')
        poll_data.append(data)
    return poll_data


read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')
```

Comment: "I don't believe there is an issue with the rest of the code as if I replaced 'return poll data' with 'print(poll_data)' there is the desired output." - if you're going to do this, you'd have to make that final line `print(read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')`

Comment: What @n1c9 said. The best way to check to see if there's *any* output is to `print(function(args))`

Comment: So if i need to use the result of the function, but I also want the function to actually show the output of the result, I would include 
"print(read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')" after the 'return poll_data'? or would the user have to actually use the print function to show the output?

Comment: please refer to my (and @heather's) answer for that info

Answer (score 2):

you changed that last line in the function from `print` to `return`.  So, when you call your function as such:

`read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')`

it *does* return that data.  It's sitting right there!  But then your script ends, doing nothing with that data.  so, instead, do something like this:

```
data = read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')
print(data)
```

a short addendum - political data is an excellent way to learn data manipulation with Python and, if so inclined, Python itself.  I'd recommend the O'Reilly books on data & Python - but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: You beat me by 49 seconds. =)

Comment: :) yours was more explanatory, though!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Replacing `return poll_data` with `print poll_data`.
2. Instead of `read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')`, you can do `print read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')`.

Why do you need to do this?

**`Print` vs `Return`**

`print` actually shows you the result, while `return` only gives the result to the computer, if that makes sense. The computer knows it, but it doesn't print it, which is why the second solution works - the computer has the data you want, and it is able to print it if you command it too. However, in your case, the first solution is probably easier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the above(or not so above anymore xD) answer...

the full code would now be,

```
def read_data_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    poll_data = []
    for data in file:
        data = data.strip('\n')
        data = data.split(',')
        poll_data.append(data)
    return poll_data


print(read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')) # Before you forgot to print it.
```

or exactly like the above answer,

```
def read_data_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    poll_data = []
    for data in file:
        data = data.strip('\n')
        data = data.split(',')
        poll_data.append(data)
    return poll_data


data = read_data_file('florida-gop.csv')
print(data)
```